# Comparing byte arrays with EF Core InMemoryDatabase for unit testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using the InMemoryDatabase provider, the `==` operator does a normal reference comparison of byte arrays the same as it would for any 2 ordinary byte arrays in memory. When doing a query against an actual database the same operator is translated to a SQL command using `=` which does a sequence comparison.

I have a few queries that look up a User using their Windows SID which is a byte array type, for example:

```
AppUser user = await appContext.AppUsers
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.WindowsSid == currentIdentitySid);
```

In normal operation with a real database they work, but I am unable to unit test them because the queries in unit tests still do a reference comparison. If I change the query to use `.SequenceEqual` instead of `==` then they work, but that doesn't get translated to SQL when using a real database. There is a documented issue for this here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13260

In the meantime, is there any way possible to do a `byte[]` comparison that will work with the InMemoryDatabase as well as a real one?

Comment: While not a direct answer, have you looked into using SqLite as the Unit Test EF provider? SqLite should behave the same as your backend database, and also enforces referential integrity. There were several core weaknesses with the in memory database (such as byte array comparisons) that forced us to migrate our tests solely to SqLite here.

Comment: @JDDavis I've considered it but I was hoping not to have to. Oddly enough this used to work prior to EF Core 3.0 due to a "bug" with byte arrays not being deep copied to the database and reference comparisons working as as result.

Comment: [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) advises "EF Core database providers do not have to be relational databases. InMemory is designed to be a general purpose database for testing, and is not designed to mimic a relational database."  SqlLite is recommended if you need to model relational database behavior.

Comment: I played around some with Sqlite InMemory, unfortunately our DbContext entities are all using `.HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())")` and such everywhere and it would fail when I called `Database.EnsureCreated()`.